# Importing google contacts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

Hi I want to retrieve google contacts in my default MVC5 Application.
I get login successfully using code below.

```
 GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
 {
                ClientId = "<ClientId>",
                ClientSecret = "<ClientSecret>",
                AccessType = "offline",
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                    {                        
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("accessToken", context.AccessToken))

                        if (context.RefreshToken != null)
                        {
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("refreshToken", context.RefreshToken));
                        }                      
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("EmailAddressFieldName", context.Email));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("NameFieldName", context.Name));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("TokenIssuedFieldName", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("TokenExpiresInFieldName",
                            ((long)context.ExpiresIn.Value.TotalSeconds).ToString()));

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            };


            //googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds");
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

Upon confirmation of authentication I save my AccessToken and RefreshToken to ASPNetUserClaims table in my callbackmethod in Account Controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        //one things to be noted is when i use googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"); as commented above this info is null
        //not sure why
                if (info == null)
                {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var accessToken = info.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "accessToken");
                        var refreshToken = info.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "refreshToken");
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, accessToken);
                        await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, refreshToken);
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Anyway when I am loged in using google credentials now I want to retrieve google contacts in HomeController in Contacts Method Using google Client Libraries as in code below.

```
public ActionResult Contact()
        {          
            var user= UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            var claim = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims;          
            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
            parameters.AccessToken = claim.Where(i => i.Type == "accessToken").Select(i => i.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            parameters.RefreshToken = claim.Where(i => i.Type == "refreshToken").Select(i => i.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            //parameters.Scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";           
            GetGoogleContacts(parameters);
            return View();
        }

        private static void GetGoogleContacts(OAuth2Parameters parameters)
        {
           try {
               RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("MvcAuth",parameters); 
               ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
               Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts(); 
               foreach (Contact c in f.Entries) 
               { 
                   Console.WriteLine(c.Name.FullName); 
               } 
           } 
           catch (Exception a) 
           { 
               Console.WriteLine("A Google Apps error occurred."); 
               Console.WriteLine(); 
           }

        }
```

But I get Exception 
"Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Which mean my accesstoken is not Valid if it is not valid than why. how can I get my google contacts. Please help I have spent almost 5 days on it 
but was not successfull. I just want to retrieve google contacts when I am logged in using Owin middleware component UseGoogleAuthentication()

Comment: What is ContactsRequest how are you applying the access token?

Comment: I am using .Net Client Library for ContactsRequest see link below https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/                              and I am passing accessToken as an OAuth2Parameters

Comment: Actually I am following this Tutorial http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/   but I am getting accessToken from Aspnet claims that I stored in external callback fuction when successfully authenticated using owin middleware component usegoogleauthentication()

Comment: You need to get the refresh token from asp. Net then feed that to the library

Comment: Actually I am feeding both accessToken and  refreshToken in the Library like this  OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
            parameters.AccessToken = claim.Where(i => i.Type == "accessToken").Select(i => i.Value).SingleOrDefault();
            parameters.RefreshToken = claim.Where(i => i.Type == "refreshToken").Select(i => i.Value).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

First , you must be sure the acess Token & Refersh Token has been saved in cliam Table , 
Second, You should know Access Token has date fro 1 hour